# Tuning SVM parameters in R - Overfitting

Tags: r, classification, libsvm

I am currently working on a project where I need to train an SVM (RBF kernel) classifier for a binary classification problem. I am using R and LIBSVM (package `e1071)` and was exploring the use of the `tune` function to adjust the parameters of my SVM.

My R code is the following:

```
svmTune <- tune(svm, train.x=x, train.y=y, kernel='radial',
                ranges=list(cost=10^(-5:5), gamma=seq(0, 100, 0.5)))
```

Considering the fact that, in my problem, I am dealing with an unbalanced dataset I also considered adding a `class.weights` argument:

```
svmTune <- tune(svm, train.x=x, train.y=y, kernel='radial',
                ranges=list(cost=10^(-5:5), gamma=seq(0, 100, 0.5)),
                class.weights=c('0'=numZeros/(numZeros+numOnes),
                                '1'=numOnes/(numZeros+numOnes)))
```

My problem is that I seem to be getting an useless classifier: I always get as the best model (`svmTune$best.model`) an SVM with the same number of support vectors as the length of the training data (or extremely close, like 34 S.V. for 35 training instances); and this model either memorises the training data (has AUC of 1 over training data) or fails miserably at predicting it (AUC of 0.5). Regarding the performance on the test data I always get an AUC of 0.5...

I know that we can create a `tune.control` object to tweak several control parameters, and I have also tried to change some of its parameters but seem to be unable to improve my results....

Could someone help me understand what am I doing wrong? Am I not supposed to be trying several parameters for an SVM in an automated way like this?

Answer (score 0):

This seems like a case of overfitting. Since there are so few datapoints it's not strange that the algorithm defaults to just memorizing the data. Try reading about cross validation for parameter tuning and/or model selection, there are a lot of great sources online. This book has a lot of examples using R: http://www-bcf.usc.edu/~gareth/ISL/